# Calculation results in unexpected 0

Tags: c++

I am having a problem with my calculations giving me a 0 as a result. I am writing a program that gets user to input time in hours, minutes, and seconds then converts and outputs the time in seconds. No matter the input the answer always gives me a 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int hours = 0, min = 0, sec = 0, total = 0;

    total = (((hours * 60) * 60) + (min * 60) + sec);

    cout << "Please Enter hours, minutes, and seconds" << endl;
    cin >> hours >> min >> sec;
    cout << "Your time in seconds is" << total;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calculating the output before you read the user input. Instead of:

```
total = (((hours * 60) * 60) + (min * 60) + sec);

cout << "Please Enter hours, minutes, and seconds" << endl;
cin >> hours >> min >> sec;
```

use

```
cout << "Please Enter hours, minutes, and seconds" << endl;
cin >> hours >> min >> sec;
total = (((hours * 60) * 60) + (min * 60) + sec);
```

Comment: Thanks that works! I can't believe that was it... I spent hours looking through my textbook.